# I am getting disconnected from DSL modem and can't connect unless I restart.

Tags: adsl

I am using Ubuntu very recently. My DSL connection with the modem is working fine but after certain idle time the modem connection is getting disconnected and I am not getting the icons to reconnect. If I go to System Settings--> Network, it is showing "Network cable is unplugged". It works fine if i reboot. This is a sudden problem and no configuration has been altered. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 with latest updates.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link it helped me
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Connecting_an_Ubuntu_Linux_System_to_a_DSL_Modem

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.